# Why the value of Abrikosov beta parameter is a sum of series?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

The order parameter $\psi(x,y)$ can be written as :
\begin{equation}
\psi(x,y)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n\exp{(inky)}\exp\left[{-\kappa^2\over2}\left(x-{nk\over\kappa^2}\right)^2\right]
\end{equation}
where $\psi\left(x,y+L_y\right)=\psi(x,y+{2\pi\over k})=\psi(x,y),\quad L_x={k\over \kappa^2}$. And the Abrikosov parameter is defined as :
\begin{equation}
\beta_A={\left<|\psi|^4\right>\over\left<|\psi|^2\right>^2}
\end{equation}
However, for square lattice ($C_n=1$), $\beta_A$ can be described as a sum of series,
\begin{equation}
\beta_A={k\over\kappa\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-{k^2n^2\over2
\kappa^2}\right]\right)^2
\end{equation}
But I don't know how to derive this equation.